# how to handle multiple promises in async javascript function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

see example below, I have an async function, I want to add a fetch call and make sure it returns before
making a call to another function getCustomerData which returns a promise.
how do i make sure my first api call is returned and complete before , i make a second call. I've noticed
in my testing that code below, produces error because it looks likes at time second call is executed before first call is completed/returned.

```
async function getRecords() {
   
   //first api call
   fetch('api/getCustomerDetails', options).then(). catch(); 

   //second call 
   let response = await getCusotomerData().promise(); 
}
```

Comment: did you try adding await on the fetch line ?

Comment: await fot the first mline so to execution sequence stops until it finishes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only need to add await ,async function means nothing without it, it simply waits for each process that comes after awaits keyword to finish before going to the next line of code .

then() and catch() will execute depending on the value of the fetch but they dont control the execution of code . for example you can put your second line in the then() and it will work the same as await .

*usually you work with await or then & catch*

```
async function getRecords() {
   
   //first api call
   await fetch('api/getCustomerDetails', options).then().catch(); 

   //second call 
   let response = await getCusotomerData().promise(); 
}
```

```
async function fn() {       // asynchronous function
   
   await process_a          // the await will not allow anything to happen before process_a finishs

   process_b                // this will wait for process_a to finish
}
```

you still need to verify the result of **process_a** so use *its* try & catch

```
async function getRecords() {
   
   //first api call
   fetch('api/getCustomerDetails', options).then(()=>{
         //second call in case first one is success
         let response = await getCusotomerData().promise(); 
         }).catch(()=>{
             //handle first api call errors here
         });
}
```

or use the try catch block in the answer below

Comment: want to confirm by second line in your answer you mean the second call , right?

Comment: yes , the now the getCustomerData().promise() will *wait* whatever comes before it and has the await keyword .

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this.  I think the cleanest is with try/catch

```js
async function getRecords() {
   try{
       await fetch('api/getCustomerDetails', options)
       let response = await getCusotomerData().promise(); 
   } catch(e) {
       // error handling here
   }
}
```

Using `await` in front of the `fetch` call assures that the following lines won't execute until the fetch promise is complete.  You may want to have more specific error catching logic, as the above block will catch any issues that arise in the entire try block, but you may want to catch errors on a more granular level (i.e. a `.catch` for the fetch).

Comment: thanks. I followed a tutorial for fetch and add fetch().then().catch() construct . do i need to add await fetch().then().catch()?

Comment: You *can*....doing `await fetch(url).then(callback)` within a try/catch block can be kind of silly if there's not much else going on in the block, but it is valid.  doing `await fetch(url).catch(errorCallback)` in a try/catch means that you'll be catching any errors on *that fetch*, as opposed to within the entire try block, which is what my answer does.  It just depends on how you want to organize the flow of things.

Comment: but as @HijenHEK said, you usually do async/await with try/catch, ***or*** .then().catch() syntax.  You *can* mix them, but its generally best not to, as it can get confusing.